# How is $X\models\bot\Rightarrow X\models\alpha$ to be understood?[Solved]

Tags: logic

Usually you write $X\models\alpha$ if $\omega\models\alpha$ takes effect for every model $\omega$ for the set $X$, meaning that $\alpha$ can be deduced from $X$. My Question is the following. I understood that if $X\models\bot$ takes effect, it means that $X$ has no model $\omega$. An example set would be $X=\{p,\neg p\}$. So how can $X\models\bot\Rightarrow X\models\alpha$ be true if there is no model $\omega$ for $X$ which could even fulfill $\omega\models\alpha$. This concept is only known for me in the areas of tautology. There a tautology $\alpha$ can be deduced from the empty set which too has no model. But in this case $\alpha$ is not specified to be a tautology.

Comment: $X  \models \alpha$ means that _if_ $M$ is model of $X$, _then_ $M$ is also a model of $\alpha$. If $X$ has _no_ models, then the conditional in the previous sentence is vacuously true.

Comment: @aduh: That was a perfectly good answer; you ought to undelete it, so as to make sure that the question doesn’t end up on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \vDash \bot$, then - as you say - $X$ has no model.

Thus, consider the definition of $\vDash$ :

> $\Gamma$ *tautologically implies* $\varphi$ (written : $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) iff every truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\varphi$.

and apply it to the $X$ above.

We have that **no** truth assignment satisfy $X$, and thus it is vacuously true that every truth assignment that satisfy $X$ satisfy also $\alpha$, i.e.

> > $X \vDash \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the principle of explosion.

It's pretty straightforward that $\vDash \bot\rightarrow \alpha$ for any $\alpha$. If we know that $\Gamma \vDash \bot$ then, from above, we get that $\Gamma\vDash \alpha$.

This is saying that if from your set of premises you can deduce a contradiction, you can deduce anything from it.